# :target element on page load

Tags: css, target

Is it possible to have an element `:target`ed when the page loads?

The site has several language choices, each of which display only on `:target`. When index.htm loads, none is `:target`ed – I'd rather have the user see one of the languages.

(example: burlupar.info)

Comment: You won't be able to do that with `:target`. You could use a bit of JS, though. Make sure to optimize the large image, though. It takes ages to load—not good.

Comment: Fix'd. Cheers. @ralph.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option here is to avoid relying on :target for the display/hide of the languages.

The standard is to set each of the language divs as display:none, and then use JavaScript to show/hide the divs as needed.

For example, I would use jQuery's show (http://api.jquery.com/show/) and hide (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) functions to toggle the language display when one of the links is clicked.  Once that is set up you can simply have one of the languages set to display in CSS by default.