# Target Selectors in HTML5 Tab won't display content by default

Tags: html, css

I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, but for some reason I can't get the #teams ID to display the text: **this is a squad by default.** Instead I have to click on one of the words in order to make the text appear.

Can anyone one out there show me how to make the teams id and its content appear by default?

```
<div class="sports">
    <a href="#teams" id="teams">
        Team
        <div>
            <p>This is a squad...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#athletes" id="athletes">
        Athletes
        <div>
            <p>This is a guy..</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#coaches" id="coaches">
        Coaches
        <div>
            <p>This is an old man...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.sports {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0; display:block;
}


div.sports > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1em;
}

div.sports > a + a {
    margin-left:10px;
}

div.sports > a:target {
    color:#33CCFF;
}

div.sports > a > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    display: none;
    color: #8D8D8D;
}

div.sports > a:target > div {
    display: block;
}


div.sports > a:target > div {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ED6cH/196/

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158747/target-element-on-page-load

Comment: `<div>` nested in an `<a>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Load the page with `#teams` at the end of the Url

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ED6cH/196/show/#teams

This is one of the limitations of `:target`

You could also use javasctipt/jQuery to add `#teams` if there is no hash in the url  on page load.

To do this with javasctipt add the following in script tags

```
if(window.location.hash == null || window.location.hash = ""){
    window.location.hash = "#teams";
}
```

Comment: How would I go about adding jquey or js to this?